# How to center multiple divs (floated left) contained within another div

Tags: html, css

Edit: Apologies to those who answered the original question that didn't included the complication with the unordered lists.

Whenever I put multiple div elements **containing unordered lists** into another div element, I can't center the inner div elements. Here's a simple illustration and the accompanying code:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-Ca" xml:lang="en-Ca">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {
                border:solid;
                overflow:hidden;
                width:40%;
            }
            #one, #two, #three {
                border: solid red;
                display:inline-block;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            .clear {
                clear:both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
            <div id="one">
                <ul>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                    <li>Three</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="two">
            <ul>
                <li>Four</li>
                <li>Five</li>
                <li>Six</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="three">
            <ul>
                <li>Seven</li>
                <li>Eight</li>
                <li>Nine</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whether I put display:inline-block or float:left doesn't seem to make any difference, nor does adding a wrapper class or specifying a width. How do I center the three red boxes within the black box?

Comment: Set Container to `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Float left means that you don't want something to be centered but to go left. Margin 0 auto means that you want something to be centered. What do you want of those two options?

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`.

Comment: You should post real html with ul's and li's and real css so we could help you instead this one with divs which doesn't even reflect your problem.

Comment: I fixed the example, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind using CSS3 only solution? If not, you could use the flex-box model see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If you want it to work in CSS2 also, the `margin: 0 auto` only works correctly on elements with a specified with. You could hack this by using inline blocks with a `white-space: pre` and `text-align: center`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/aX8AG/3/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>
    </ul>
    <ul><li>AAA</li><li>BBB</li><li>CCCC</li></ul>
    <ul><li>AA</li><li>BB</li><li>CC</li></ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {    
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Note: I changed the float on the li to be inline-blocks, note that whitespace between LI's is still unwanted, but whitespace between UL is allowed now

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use white-space:pre; ?

Comment: The whitespace pre is used to be able to use a normal enter as a line break. Actually i noticed this solution can be build even better... see update in answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Create a new container for the boxes, and center that: http://jsfiddle.net/ugh5M/:

```
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:30%;
}
```

Comment: Don't need an extra wrapper, just set margin on container.

Comment: Putting the margin there will center the container, and not the contents within.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
float: left;
```

statement to center the red boxes...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
    #one, #two, #three {
        border: solid red;
        float:left; <------ Take this out and they will center
        width:30%;
        margin:0 auto; /* doesn't do anything */
    }
```

Do this:

```
    #one, #two, #three {
        border: solid red;
        width:30%;
        margin:0 auto; /* does something */
    }
```

It works if you look here: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tSFL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: left;` because it will overwrite the `margin: 0px auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/152/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are floating and then clearing both, it seems counter intuitive?

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
            <div id="one">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum nec nibh ut fringilla. Vestibulum egestas velit quis blandit 
                imperdiet. Nullam sollicitudin commodo odio. Mauris pharetra arcu vel porta dignissim.
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="two">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum nec nibh ut fringilla. Vestibulum egestas velit quis blandit 
            imperdiet. Nullam sollicitudin commodo odio. Mauris pharetra arcu vel porta dignissim.
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="three">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum nec nibh ut fringilla. Vestibulum egestas velit quis blandit 
            imperdiet. Nullam sollicitudin commodo odio. Mauris pharetra arcu vel porta dignissim.
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
                border:solid;
                overflow:hidden;
                width:50%;
            }
            #one, #two, #three {
                border: solid red;
                width:30%;
                margin:0 auto; /* doesn't do anything */
            }
```

Demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jerryhuangme/bdVcm/